# Execute generic end to end test in Azure Pipelines from seperate repository

Tags: automated-tests, azure-pipelines, mstest

Im working with a project in Azure DevOps. The project is spread out in multiple repositories containing Azure functions, logic apps etc with multiple CI/CD Pipelines. Currently I'm working on an end-to-end testsolution for this project.

I would like to have the tests in a seperate repository and be able to trigger the tests when other CD-pipelines run. How can I accomplish this? The tests are built with MSTest and are currently run in a build-pipeline.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to try out below solution? Free to let me know if there is any question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rest api to trigger the tests when other CD-pipelines run.

If you want to run the tests in a separate CI pipeline. You need to create a CI pipeline to run the tests for this test repository. Then add a script task in the CD pipeline to call [build queue restful api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#definitionreference). Please check below script example in powershell task.

```
$url = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1"

$qbody = '{ 
                "definition": {
                   "id": "the definition id of the test CI pipeline"    
                  } 
              }'

$update = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -ContentType "application/json"  -Method post -Body $qbody
```

You aslo need to go to the agent job and check `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token`.
[image]

Another way to trigger the test CI pipeline from CD pipeline is to add [Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline&targetId=47097972-e633-4284-ad72-fe49f3c8dd5f) in CD pipeline and configure it to trigger the test CI pipeline.